# Remove record from mysql after given time in javascript/spring boot

Tags: javascript, mysql, spring-boot

Let's say there is a website in html/js where I have a table Users in mysql with following records

```
Mark  | Start:  9:00 | End:17:00
Julia | Start: 10:00 | End:18:00
```

User clicks own name, enters working hours on the everyday basis. Mysql record is being updated with POST request. **Spring boot** is on the backend. This is not a login process. There is no session here. This interface updates start & end hour in mysql.

I'd like to remove User Mark working hours in mysql after his given time. It's a simple process of wiping hours column in mysql after given time.

How I suppose to implement it?

I was thinking to run a thread which checks every 15 minutes working hours  from the database and compare with current time or use cron job on the server. Are there any way how to do it. Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: misunderstood the question.

As commented below, try spring `@Shecduled` annotation. I provided a cron expression that will run every 15 minutes on weekdays.

```
@Scheduled(cron="0 0/15 * ? * MON-FRI")
public void doSomething() {
    // Do your database stuff here...
}
```

[Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled)

Comment: thank you for reply but I incorrectly asked. I'm not creating any session.I edited my question to make it more clear

Comment: In that case try: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled

`@Scheduled(fixedRate=5000)
public void doSomething() {
    // something that should execute periodically
}`